# How to retain Select option after submitting the form in php

Tags: php, html, web-applications

I looked at several community forums, and I am unable to figure it out on how to retain select option value after validation fails.

Here is the code that works for me, but values disappear when submit button is submitted.

```
<select id="service" name="service" class="searchoption">
             <option value="">-- Select Service Name --</option>
             <?php
             $resultservice = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from services") ?>
             <?php
             while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($resultservice)) {
             ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $line['serviceid'];?>"> <?php echo $line['service'];?> </option>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

Here is what I tried and doesn't work for me:

```
<select id="service" name="service" class="searchoption">
             <option value="">-- Select Service Name --</option>
             <?php
             $resultservice = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from services") ?>
             <?php
             while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($resultservice)) {
             ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $line['serviceid']; if ($_POST['service'] == $service) {echo 'selected="selected"'} echo $line['serviceid']; ?>"> <?php echo $line['service'];?> </option>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: did you submit your form in same page?

Comment: You are echoing `selected` attribute within `value` attribute

Comment: Hi Awlad, Thanks for your quick response, yes I am submitting to same page.

Comment: Rahil, I dont understand what you mean by I am echoing selected attribute value attribute. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="list" id="list">
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('list').value = "<?php echo $_POST['list']?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I tried this and it didn't work for me. <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('list').value = "<?php echo $_POST['list']?>";
</script>

Comment: I mean like this <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById('service').value = "<?php echo $_POST['service']?>";
        </script>

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, you need to put the script tags after the form tag.

Comment: You mean after opening of Form tag? or after closing of form tag? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Yes after the closing form tag.

Answer (score -2):

May be a small error but noticed a invalid > in the following code

```
 <option value="<?php echo $line['serviceid']; if ($_POST['service'] == $service) {echo 'selected="selected"'} echo $line['serviceid']; ?>"> <?php echo $line['service'];?> </option>
```

Try this

```
 <option value="<?php echo $line['serviceid']; if ($_POST['service'] == $service) {echo     'selected="selected"'}?> echo $line['serviceid']; <?php echo $line['service'];?>" </option>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Nice I didn't noticed that. I will remove it and will try again.

Comment: Hello John, that didn't work for me. When I tried your suggestion, page didn't load at all.

Comment: Yes sorry you have closed the tag before you call the service string move the > to after the double quotes

Comment: you mean like this? <option value="<?php echo $line['serviceid']; if ($_POST['service'] == $service) {echo 'selected="selected"'}?>"> echo $line['serviceid']; <?php echo $line['service'];?>" </option>